# No Action while SmoothScrollToPosition in Custom List View

Tags: java, android, listview

Hi I m using below code where when user touches the textview , list will be updated and touched list row will be in front of user.

```
public class AppAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<AppList> listStorage;
    private Context context;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    int pos = 0;

    public AppAdapter(Context context, List<AppList> customizedListView) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        listStorage = customizedListView;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        pos = sharedPreferences.getInt("pos", 0);
        Log.e("POS",pos+"At Get cpiunt");
        return listStorage.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();


        ViewHolder listViewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            listViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_app_list, parent, false);

            listViewHolder.textInListView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_app_name);
            listViewHolder.imageInListView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);
            convertView.setTag(listViewHolder);
        } else {
            listViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        listViewHolder.textInListView.setText(listStorage.get(position).getName());
        listViewHolder.imageInListView.setImageDrawable(listStorage.get(position).getIcon());


        listViewHolder.textInListView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                editor.putInt("pos", position).apply();
                Log.e("Pressed", position + "");
                MainActivity.installedAppAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.e("Saved", sharedPreferences.getInt("pos", 0) + "value");
            }
        });


        if (pos != 0) {

           MainActivity.userInstalledApps.setSelection(pos);
           editor.putInt("pos",0).apply();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {

        TextView textInListView;
        ImageView imageInListView;
    }



}
```

I read many questions but did not get clear picture about how to use SmoothScrolltopostion. Though I as per info got, I captured click position and retrieved during list load to set saved position of list to user.

If I use smoothscrolltoposition, there is no action, but if I use setselection as shown in above code, I could able to see the clicked item in top of view after reloading.

Why smoothscroll is not working and m I doing correct coding for required action. pls guide.